# Will GNOME3 installation break Lubuntu?

Tags: gnome, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu on my netbook and I'm wondering whether it is safe to install GNOME3 via PPA or if it will break the system just like in Ubuntu. My logical thought is that since there is no GNOME, there's nothing to break, but I' d like to have this confirmed. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the GNOME 3 PPA is an experimental developer preview and is not recommended for install, even if you are only using Lubuntu.